# What is the tension at centre of rarefraction of spring with a travelling longitudinal wave

Tags: waves

When a travelling longitudinal wave pass through a slinky spring, the displacement of particle at centre of rarefraction is zero.By Hooke law, tension should be zero.

Howver, if we conside the region around centre of rarefraction it seems stretched and should have highest tension.
So how is tension distributed in the slinky spring?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#From_Hooke's_law) help?